Google Sheets Function to extract URL & Embed into Unique Identifier String
I have an column of Data that includes unique identifier sales opportunity ID and the Salesforce URL in the same cell. The task is to separate the Opp ID from the URL and then embed the URL into Opp ID.
Sample Data is available below:
Combined
0064M00000dEeY
Opportunity ID
[0064M00000dEeY]
URL
(https://vector.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0064M00000dEeY/view)
Combined
0064M00000cn3m
Opportunity ID
[0064M00000cn3m]
URL
(https://vector.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0064M00000cn3m/view)
I was able to remove the Salesforce hyperlink into column B by using REGEXREPLACE.
However, I am unable to extract the hyperlink into column C.
Appreciate any guidance on the correct function to use to paste all urls into column C.
I have attempted the following methods without success:

=REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A2),"""(.+)"",") - this provides "Invalid Formula Parse Result"
=REPLACE("[A3]",1,20,"(https://vector.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0064M00000cn3mOQAQ/view)") - this returns the URL only but formula cannot be applied to the remaining cells as the formula is static and returns the URL from cell A3 only. This is not efficient, since I might as well copy and paste the URL manually for the 1500 cells.
=linkUrl(ADDRESS(ROW(A4), COLUMN(A4))) - this provides an error of "Unknown function: LinkURL".
=regexreplace(A5,"([^()]*)","")(HYPERLINK(A5)) - provides error "Invalid call to non-function".

